# How Do I Select Individual Label Folder with TFDS

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm working with file directories of images. The main directory "train" holds subfolders of images like so

```sh
train/
     One/
         image_of_a_one.png
     Two/
         image_of_a_two.png
.
.
.
```

This code loads the whole dataset however I want to isolate the ones in the dataset for an individual model (GAN) that works with images of ones.

```py
builder = tfds.builder('mnist')
builder.download_and_prepare()
ds = builder.as_dataset(split='train', shuffle_files=True)
#Now How I think I would select the one's folder is I would subscript with the label
ds['One']
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

TFDS downloads the dataset as tfrecords, so you don't have access to the directories, but you can convert the dataset to a dataframe and slice that:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
ds, info = tfds.load('mnist', split='train', with_info=True)
df = tfds.as_dataframe(ds, info)
df = df[df['label'] == 1]
```

Comment: It was an example, I'm not really using mnist, but a file directory of my own.